Arabic text is too far below the baseline
I wish to include a few Arabic numbers in my document.
I tried the package arabtex, but the numbers in arabic are below the baseline.
Does anyone know how to fix this?
A minimal example:
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrbook}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\it}{\normalfont\itshape}{\mathit}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

text text text \<123456789>text 123456789 text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text

\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE!

In order just to add Arabic digit forms in the document you don't need the full arabtex package.
First attempt:
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrbook}

\newcommand{\arabnumber}[1]{{\usefont{U}{xnsh}{m}{n}#1}}

\begin{document}

text text text \arabnumber{123456789} text 123456789 text text
text text text text text text text texttext text text text text

\end{document}


Explanation: I looked into the package and discovered the font used when \<...> is processed.
However, we can see that the problem is still there: the digits are designed to hang below the baseline.
LaTeX to the rescue!
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrbook}

\newcommand{\arabnumber}[1]{%
  \raisebox{\depth}{\usefont{U}{xnsh}{m}{n}#1}%
}

\begin{document}

text text text \arabnumber{123456789} text 123456789 text text
text text text text text text text texttext text text text text

\end{document}


